# How to calculate difference of dates in different formats in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am merging 2 huge tables in Snowflake and I have 2 columns (one on each table):

"Year_birth" and "Exam_date" and the info inside looks like this respectively:

"1918" and "2007-03-13"       (NUMBER(38,0) and VARCHAR(256))

- I only want to merge the rows where the difference (i.e., age when the exam was made) is ">18" and "<60"
- I was playing around with SELECT DATEDIFF(year,Exam_date, Year_birth) with no success.

Any ideas on how would I do it in Snowflake?

Cheers!

Comment: Doesn't Snowflake have any date data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have a year, so there is not much you can do about the specific day of the year -- you need to deal with approximations.

So, extract the year from the date string (arggh! it should really be a `date`) and just compare them:

```
where (left(datestr, 4)::int - yearnum) not between 18 and 60
```

I would strongly advise you to fix the database and store these values using a proper `date` datatype.

Comment: Hi!  I cannot edit the database itself. But let me try extracting the year from the string, might do the job!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the integer year into a date before doing a datediff

example:

```
set YearOfBirth = 1918;
set ExamDate = '2007-03-03'::DATE;
-- select $YearofBirth as YearofBirth, $ExamDate as ExamDate;
select $YearofBirth as YearofBirth,($YearofBirth::TEXT||'-01-01')::DATE as YearofBirthDate, $ExamDate as ExamDate, datediff(year,($YearofBirth::TEXT||'-01-01')::DATE,$ExamDate) as YearsSinceExam;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

USE YEARS_DIFF IN WHERE CLAUSE TO FILTER DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 18 & 60
SELECT DATEDIFF( YEAR,'2007-03-03',TO_DATE(2018::CHAR(4),'YYYY')) YEARS_DIFF;